# remap an xml feed to the address of a wordpress rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, jekyll

I used to have a blog based on Wordpress and moved to one based on Jekyll.  I can create a new feed in Jekyll by building an atom page in XML with a bit of Liquid code, [like this](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook/blob/master/atom.xml)

The trouble is, the location of the new feed is http://carlboettiger.info/atom.xml, while the old feed from the wordpress site is http://carlboettiger.info/feed, with no extension.  how can I configure the Jekyll-created feed such that followers who have pointed their readers to the old feed address from wordpress will start to get the new content?

([Site's Jekyll source here](https://github.com/cboettig/labnotebook))

Comment: Is there something about Jekyll that prevents you from just creating a basic redirect from [wpfeedurl] to [jekyllfeedurl]? The problem isn't configuring Jekyll/its feed, but just telling your server where to point people. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jekyll but wouldn't you be able to modify the feed URL in the header of your website

Comment: I'm confused about extensions actually.  Do I copy atom.xml to "feed" in my root directory, or create a new dirctory "feed" and copy the "atom.xml" to "index.html", or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all feed readers will follow redirects when fetching feeds.   You should be able modify your .htaccess file to redirect the old url to the new.

```
Redirect 301 /feed http://carlboettiger.info/atom.xml
```